Ubuntu 24.04 getting error You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list when issuing apt-get build-dep
On freshly installed from scratch (not an upgrade) Ubuntu 24.04 I get this error when I run
$ sudo apt-get build-dep -y vlc  
Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list

Prior to 24.04 fix was to make edits to /etc/apt/sources.list, but now on 24.04:
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# Ubuntu sources have moved to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources

here is new file on 24.04
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources 
Types: deb
URIs: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble noble-updates noble-backports noble-proposed
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg



Types: deb
URIs: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble-security
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

How do I add deb-src to the new file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources?

There is a new config file location with a new file format layout for 24.04 unlike previous Ubuntu releases
Add the below snippet to the new config file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources
Types: deb-src
URIs: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble noble-updates noble-backports noble-proposed
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

If you want to do this using a one line command:

sed -i 's/^Types: deb$/Types: deb deb-src/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources

final updated file will become
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources 

Types: deb deb-src
URIs: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble noble-updates noble-backports noble-proposed
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg



Types: deb deb-src 
URIs: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble-security
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

then run
sudo apt update

__________  below is server only not your laptop _______________
NOTE if the machine is under control of cloud-init (ignore this for those viewers at home this pertains to some remote cloud Ubuntu VM not your home laptop) instead make a similar addition of deb-src to the template file as per
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources 
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
##
## If you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add supplemental sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file
##      /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.ubuntu.deb822.tmpl
##


Thanks for looking that up for everyone :)
Don't forget to run apt update afterwards so that the source indexes are downloaded.

Here is a one-liner for this in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS: sed -i 's/^Types: deb/Types: deb deb-src/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources

@Utkonos  have you actually run your proposed one liner on 24.04 ?    it is not valid ... it is similar to a one liner which did work on 22.04 or earlier yet fails on 24.04

It works 100%. It came from my command history and I just tested it again because you asked: # sed -i 's/^Types: deb/Types: deb deb-src/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources # grep Types /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources ## Types: Append deb-src to enable the fetching of source package. Types: deb deb-src Types: deb deb-src

@Utkonos  Wow you are correct ... post your solution as an answer and I will checkmark yours as THE more elegant solution ... good job ...  sometimes reality is stranger than one can imagine

No need to make a second answer. Hopefully the edit that I just made will be accepted by the moderators.

Might be worthwhile doing a match for end of line with $ like so; sed -i 's/^Types: deb$/Types: deb deb-src/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources to prevent the sed command doing substitutions if run more than once.
